# comparing username and custom field in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, comparison, custom-fields

I am trying to show a message according to the logged in user and a custom field value.
If the logged in user and the custom field values are same then it should show "this page is assigned for you"

else, it should should show "this page is NOT assigned for you"

My code is for that:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$getClient = get_post_meta($postid, 'clientName', true);
echo 'Client is : '.$getClient;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo '<br/>Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';

if ($getClient !== $current_user){
    echo 'this page is NOT assigned for you';
}
else {
    echo 'this page is assigned for you';
}
```

when I go to page and if the username and the custom field values are same is shows:

```
Client is : cd_riffaz
Username: cd_riffaz
this page is NOT assigned for you
```

Actually it should show "`this page is assigned for you`" right? because the values are identical.

Why it does not work as expected?

Comment: have you var_dumped the values to see if they are actually the same?

Comment: var_dump($current_user->user_login); var_dump($getClient);

Comment: You have typo error in if it should be like this `if ($getClient != $current_user->user_login ){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing an object (`$current_user`) to a string `$getClient`.
You should do `if ($getClient !== $current_user->user_login)`

P.S. You can do `global $current_user;` instead of `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

Comment: oh yeah - And that might be it :)